# Best way to position element under another (sometimes visible) element without shoving following content down?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, position, css-float

I'm building a simple character count component to be used alongside some forms in a React app. The current character count is not visible until the text field associated with the `<CharacterCount />` component has some text in it. I'm trying to position the element below and to the far right of the input.

I've tried a few things to get the `CharacterCount` component not to "shove" the content under it down the form when it is visible, including absolutely positioning the element, using a negative margin value on the element so that it doesn't shift content when it's visible, and floating the rendered content to the right. I'm curious as to what the best approach might be here. All three solutions "work" but I feel weird having to set absolute values (in the cases of Absolute positioning and using negative margins) and I worry that using a float might give me weird issues if I'm not careful about with width of the elements involved.

### Absolute Positioning

Absolute positioning feels a bit finicky, granted I'm no CSS expert, but I'm having to set harder values than I'd like which makes me feel like I'm in for some unexpected behavior. I'm also in some way making things less flexible by explicitly assuming that I'm using this component inside `relative` positioned elements. In some use cases this is OK, as I have a input component (as seen below), but it does limit my ability to use the `CharacterCount` component elsewhere without modifying a bunch of CSS. According to this approach, I have something like this:

```js
// Parent componentry, custom Input component that I control
<Box sx={{ position: 'relative'}}>  <-- Annoying to have to explicitly position components
  <ThemeUIInput
    {...props}
    sx={{
      width: '100%'
    }}
  />
  {showCharacterCount && maxLength && value.length > 0 && (
    <CharacterCount
      maxCharacters={maxLength}
      currentLength={value.length}
    />
  )}
</Box>

// CharCount component and styling:
const CharacterCount = ({ maxCharacters, currentLength }) => {
  return (
    <p
      sx={{
        fontSize: '0.65rem',
        marginTop: '5px',
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '-16.5px',  <-- Feels weirdly specific
        right: '0px',
        zIndex: 2
      }}
    >
      Remaining Characters: {maxCharacters - currentLength}
    </p>
  )
}
```

This is giving more or less the desired results aside from my concern that using it on other components requires me to be careful about remembering its styling behavior:[image: An example of the UI in question using absolute positioning, with the character count displayed under the input at the far right.]

#### Floating Right

The other way I tried doing this was floating the content to the right, but I'm not sure that is the most appropriate way to do this, and I'm concerned about weird document flow issues due to floating content. As long as I'm not using a block-level/100% width element, I don't think I'll get any undesired content shift? That looked like:

```js
// Parent componentry, custom Input component that I control
<Box>  <-- No explicit positioning, which is nice 
  <ThemeUIInput
    {...props}
    sx={{
      width: '100%'
    }}
  />
  {showCharacterCount && maxLength && value.length > 0 && (
    <CharacterCount
      maxCharacters={maxLength}
      currentLength={value.length}
    />
  )}
</Box>

// Charcount component and styling
const CharacterCount = ({ maxCharacters, currentLength }) => {
  return (
    <p
      sx={{
        fontSize: '0.65rem',
        marginTop: '5px',
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        float: 'right'  <-- Float right
      }}
    >
      Remaining Characters: {maxCharacters - currentLength}
    </p>
  )
}
```

[image: An example of the form UI using a float: right rule, with the character count displayed under the input at the far right.]

So far I think I'm leaning towards the float, but I'll be honest, reading everything about floats is a bit confusing to me. All I've gathered is that floats are usually used to get stuff to conform/wrap gracefully around other elements that are "oddly" positioned, and they change (my) expected document flow.

Am I overlooking anything more simple/fundamental? I have a tendency to overcomplicate this stuff.

Comment: In terms of fundamental, your character count component probably shouldn't define anything at all about where it is placed. That's for a higher level component to determine.

Comment: @alohci That's not a bad point, but I also don't know how I feel about the pattern being that you have to manually style the component whenever it's used. In my mind there's some "chicken vs. egg" there, but I do agree that it's nice to avoid making the components overly opinionated in any way. By convention, we have a little UI library that does apply certain styles to almost all the UI components we use.

Answer (score -1):

What about putting both the box and CharacterCount within another container and using flex properties? You can set the container to `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` and in your CharacterCount `align-self: flex-end;`

Consider the code below:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.first-box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.second-box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="first-box"></div>
  <div class="second-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what occurred to me first but the main thing I'm trying to accomplish is for the character count text to not displace any of the content underneath it. I guess the default could possibly be a thing like `1/100 characters used` or something similar but yeah for my edification in this case I was wondering how best to do it without shifting stuff around vertically.